# Comunicação entre View e Controller através de um script

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou tentando chamar uma Action através do .ajax que roda dentro de um botão de um Modal mas aparentemente a url não é processada. 
Minha View está assim:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <h2>Resfriador</h2>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data_Coleta, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data_Coleta, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data_Coleta, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hora_Coleta, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hora_Coleta, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hora_Coleta, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KW_entrada_resfriador, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KW_entrada_resfriador, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KW_entrada_resfriador, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AG_entrada_resfriador, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AG_entrada_resfriador, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AG_entrada_resfriador, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WGW_entrada_resfriador, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WGW_entrada_resfriador, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WGW_entrada_resfriador, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.normal_temp_inicial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.normal_temp_inicial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.normal_temp_inicial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.normal_temp_final, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.normal_temp_final, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.normal_temp_final, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.moido_temp_inicial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.moido_temp_inicial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.moido_temp_inicial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.moido_temp_final, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.moido_temp_final, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.moido_temp_final, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.granulometria63, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.granulometria63, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.granulometria63, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.granulometria200, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.granulometria200, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.granulometria200, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.temp_entrada, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.temp_entrada, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.temp_entrada, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.temp_saida, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.temp_saida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.temp_saida, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        @if (ViewBag.Message == "Negado") 
            {
                <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <h4>ATENÇÃO!</h4>
                                <p id="demo">
                                    Valor fora do parâmetro. Deseja salvar?
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btnSalvar" id="Salvar" onclick="myFunction(this.id)" >Salvar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
```

Script:

```
   @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#myModal').modal('show');

            });
        </script>

        <script>
            function myFunction(value)
            {
                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST'
                        url:' @Url.Action("Salvar", "ResfriadorLAB") ',
                    })
             };
       </script>
}
```

Action Salvar:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Salvar(ResfriadorLAB resfriadorLAB)
        {
            var objlogin = db.Login.OrderByDescending(p => p.LoginId).FirstOrDefault();
            var objref = db.ReferenciasLABs.OrderByDescending(p => p.ReferenciasLABId).FirstOrDefault();

            resfriadorLAB.Data_Cadastro = DateTime.Today;
            resfriadorLAB.Hora_Cadastro = DateTime.Now;
            resfriadorLAB.LoginId = objlogin.UsuarioId;
            resfriadorLAB.ReferenciasLABId = objref.ReferenciasLABId;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.ResfriadorLABs.Add(resfriadorLAB);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.LoginId = new SelectList(db.Login, "LoginId", "LoginId", resfriadorLAB.LoginId);
            ViewBag.ReferenciasLABId = new SelectList(db.ReferenciasLABs, "ReferenciasLABId", "ReferenciasLABId", resfriadorLAB.ReferenciasLABId);
            return View(resfriadorLAB);
        }
```

Quando clico no botão Salvar de dentro da Modal não acontece nada. Já tentei colocar a url: '~/ResfriadorLAB/Salvar' e também usar o método callPostBack mas mesmo assim não consigo abrir a Action Salvar. Preciso salvar mesmo quando o valor cadastrado está fora do parâmetro de validação. Alguém consegue ver o porquê do botão não direcionar para Action?

Comment: Com aquele ValidateAntiForgeryToken você não vai conseguir acessar via Ajax.

Comment: No entanto, eu não entendi o que você quer que aconteça, você está tentando fazer um formulário ser postado? ou chamar essa action por ajax sem passar nada? porque essa classe ResfriadorLAB não será preenchida a menos que você faça o submite de um formulário, ou construa um JSON com as propriedades.

Comment: Mas sem o ValidateAntiForgeryToken dá o erro:                                   Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.

O campo de formulário antifalsificação "__RequestVerificationToken" não está presente.

Comment: Então Ana, está um pouco vago a explicação. :-( eu não estou entendendo o que você quer fazer, existe um formulário na tela com esse Token?

Comment: Obrigado Ana. Então, este BeginForm não vai processar por Ajax, você precisa usar o Ajax.BeginForm dá uma olhada neste artigo, ele ensina como utilizar https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-AjaxBeginForm-Tutorial-with-example.aspx

Comment: Eu acabei de atualizar meu formulário na resposta. Eu estou colocando os dados através da View Create e ao clicar no botão salvar faço a validação dos dados no Controller através de uma tabela de Referencias previamente cadastrada no banco. Se algo não estiver ok, sinalizo para a View  através de um ViewBag.Message e a View por sua vez abre o Modal com a mensagem de confirmação. O problema é que eu preciso conseguir salvar no banco mesmo quando os dados não estiverem ok. Por isso quero chamar a Action Salvar ao clicar no botão Salvar do Modal. Espero ter conseguido me explicar, rs.

Comment: Vou olhar! Muito obrigada! :)

Comment: De nada, então, o que você pode fazer é tirar esse onclick e deixar o formulário submeter sozinho. porém o código do modal precisa estar dentro do formulário, ou então coloca o atributo form=idFormulario no botão salvar, pra ele saber qual formulário ele pertence, ai bota um id no seu formulário.

Comment: `url:'@Url.Action("Salvar", "ResfriadorLAB")'` Não são os espaços?